# Angular component: How can I force an output to be handled by parent component?

Tags: angular, output, throw

I have a child component FileUploadComponent that can be used by multiple parent component.
The FileUploadComponent has an output that I want to ensure it's handled by ALL parent components.

How can I throw an exception, from the FileUploadComponent, if the output is not handled by one of the parent ?

What I mean by "handled by the parent":

```
<app-file-upload #campaignFiles
    ...
    (documentsLoaded)="onDocumentsLoaded($event)">
</app-file-upload>
```

Thanks for your help.

Comment: Why cannot the FileUploadComponent handle it? You can't force a parent to do something as a child.

Comment: You mean that you want to make sure that all parents that can have this child implement the onDocumentsLoaded function?

Comment: @DaniloKörber: "Why cannot the FileUploadComponent handle it?" Yes that's what I'm asking. Below answer by mbojko seems to do the job

Comment: @MikeOne: Yes correct. I want that all parents implementing the child implement the onDocumentsLoaded. And the child ensures itself that it's done. Answer by mbojko below seems to do the job.

Comment: That answer is a cool trick - but it really only ensures there is an output handler set. If you comment out the actual function inside app.component, it still shows as okay. But if that is fine for you, great!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can check the `observed` property of the EventEmitter:

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
  if (this.myOutput.observed) {
// we are fine
  } else {
// we have a problem
  }
}
```

(Or alternatively this.myOutput.observed.length, but it's deprecated. Depends on the version of RxJS).

Here's a stackblitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-mtkweq?file=src%2Fapp%2Fhello.component.ts

Comment: many thanks for your help. That's exactly what I was looking for. It seems I'm using an older version of RxJS than you as `observed` doesn't exists, but I can use "observers.length".

Comment: Just to know the under the hood, check https://github.com/ReactiveX/rxjs/blob/master/src/internal/Subject.ts, because EventEmitter extends a Subject.

Answer (score 0):

You can do a hack using the selector like this:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-file-upload[documentsLoaded]',
  ...
})
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, good to know. It's very great as it throws an error in console AND app not usable (so really force to implement) but error is not meaningful. I prefer the soft solution above : I can throw an error (in console + toast) with a specific message and that's very meaningful

Comment: Yes, of course, is the best solution. It was just a hack to do that.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks all for your help.
To anyone coming to this post, based on the accepted answer, I'm throwing an error + a toast containing the parentComponent name (to whom the output is not handled) and the child component name (to know where to fix the parent component implementation)

```
ngAfterViewInit() {
    // with newer version of RxJS, use observed i/o observers.length as get deprecated
    if (this.documentsLoaded.observers.length == 0) {
      const onComponent = this.activatedRoute.snapshot.routeConfig.component.name;
      const error = `The parent component '${onComponent}' should handle the output 'documentsLoaded' emitted by its child component ${FileUploadComponent.name}`;
      this.toastr.error(error, 'Bad implementation', { disableTimeOut: true, progressBar: false });
      throw error;      
    }
}
```